# Logging Generated SQL with EF Core 2 and Nlog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nlog

I'm getting a little confused with how to log the generated SQL with asp.net core 2 and EntityFrameworkCore 2 and the correct way to go about it.

After reading the this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) from the MS docs it is saying that I should add during the services configuration in the `startup.cs` using `.UseLoggerFactory(<LoggerFactory>)`.

However, this seems outdated as when I look to add the logger I get this message;

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Message for UseLoggerFactory]

Could someone please tell me the best way to add the logger to log the SQL for debug purposes?

I also plan to use Nlog going forward for all my logging as opposed to the built in logging facilities, I assume the approach (In that the Nlog loggerfactory is injected instead of the default MS instance) for this would be the same or are there any configuration differences (with regards to using NLog)?

Comment: Well, the link you have read starts with section for [ASP.NET Core applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging#aspnet-core-applications), which states *"Therefore, when using ASP.NET Core, logging should be configured as described in the ..."* and links to [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1) which contains all the information you need.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I'm still not 100% how this works though, as have read the second link you refer to, but this is referring to injection into the controller, etc. This is fine however I am looking to (in this case just output the generated SQL from some link queries). Do I need to pass the ILogger down to my service and then down to my EF implementation? or can I not inject the logger directly into the EF implementation (which is then held in a seperate class library) and log directly from there?

Comment: See also here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2.

Comment: @Julian thanks for the link, that explains how to inject to controllers. I simply want to hook this into ef core so it logs sql queries for debugging.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn: Did you find a solution

Comment: @Stephu no unfortunately not.

Answer (score 6):

First register NLog as described on the [official docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)

Then inject an `ILoggerFactory` in your `Startup` class

```
private readonly ILoggerFactory _factory;
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory factory)
{ 
     _factory = factory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory)); 
}
```

Finally link the factory as the logger factory to use for the `DbContext`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => { options.UseLoggerFactory(_factory); });
}
```

EF Core statements are now logged using NLog
[image]

Comment: I just want to stress that this is a great answer for EF Core 2, but does not work for EF Core 3.  (Discussion of why can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9337.) I have yet to figure out the approach for EF Core 3.