# How to log Entity Framework Core operations by NLog

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, nlog, entity-framework-core-2.1

I would like to use NLog to log SQL queries from Entity Framework Core in a manner similar to WebApi Core. How can I set it up?

Answer (score 10):

For logging with  Entity Framework Core there are some docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging).

You need this: (see the docs)

```cs
public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = new LoggerFactory(new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)});
```

and use the `NLogLoggerProvider` instead of the  `ConsoleLoggerProvider`, from this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging

and something like this:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
```

also you need to load your NLog config file:

```cs
NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
```

Of course you need a nlog configuration (nlog.config or could be in C#), check https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file for that.

Update: works well according the comments :)

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking about how to log to a database; I believe they were asking how to send Entity Framework database ops (i.e. the generated SQL -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception - themselves to an NLog target.  I believe this is the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767259/logging-generated-sql-with-ef-core-2-and-nlog

Comment: @Flashlight Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767259/logging-generated-sql-with-ef-core-2-and-nlog

Comment: @Matthew   This isn't logging to the database? Don't know where you see that.  Also this answer looks a lot to the answer you have linked ;)

Comment: This answer looks correct to me. The question is how to link up a logger to the EF Core framework, and this answers it nicely. The simple answer is basically: Step 1: configure NLog. Step 2: `optionsBuilder.UserLoggerFactory(new NLogLoggerFactory())` but if you do this, you should always check `optionsBuilder.IsConfigured` before doing this. Otherwise, you're creating new logger factories all the time.