# How to log all EF queries using NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, ef-core-2.0

I need to log all query in my project and first use this:

```
public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[]
{
        new ConsoleLoggerProvider((category, level)
            => category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
            && level == LogLevel.Information, true)
});
```

but `ConsoleLoggerProvider` will removed in a future version, so I need use NLog instead `ConsoleLoggerProvider` and don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't think the console provider will be removed - just some of the constructors are obsoleted and might be removed. Anyway, for NLog take a look at [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging#nlogextensionslogging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging Generated SQL with EF Core 2 and Nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767259/logging-generated-sql-with-ef-core-2-and-nlog)

Answer (score 0):

As this is EF Core, you could use [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.extensions.logging) or [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore) for this because Microsoft is already writing the queries to the `ILogger`.

Then you could send the queries to console, database etc, just configure the nlog.config file.

Check:

- Console or unit test: [NLog: Getting started with .NET Core 2 Console application](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application)
- ASP.NET Core 2: [NLog: Getting started with ASP.NET Core 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)